# Masonry view using storyboard in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, storyboard

I already have a collection view and also the cell is defined in storyboard and its working fine, but I want the collection view to look like a [Masonry view](http://masonry.desandro.com/) as per the client requirement, but I was unable to do it . So, if any one having the idea about how to use an existing collection view as Masonry view in Objective c, then please share it. It will be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is this "Masonry"? could you show some screenshot or some other example?

Answer (score 0):

**P.S:** Masonry is a JavaScript grid layout library that adds loading effects (animation) for grid items -which in our case is `UICollectionViewCell`-.

The simplest way to add an effect (assuming that everything related to adding the collectionView and displaying cells works fine) is to implement [collectionView:willDisplayCell:forItemAtIndexPath](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618087-collectionview?language=objc) and add a sprint animation effect on the cell.

For example the following code does a fade effect to the cell, of course you can customize your animation effect:

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.alpha = 0.0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        cell.alpha = 1.0;
    }];
}
```

When scrolling it should looks like this:

[image]

Hope this helped.

Comment: No No,You have mis understood my question,actually i have implemented the collection view already but real problem is to implementing its as "MASONRY" VIEW..@Ahmed

Comment: @DevAndy man it is JavaScript library, please tell me what do you mean?

Comment: again you r mistaken.it may be javascript library.but you know i need to implement an existing collection view like masonry view.